# Can a non-GUI C#.NET application interact with OneDrive files with no user interaction?

Tags: c#, onedrive

If yes, then how?

I have files on my own OneDr2ive account. I am writing an application that will at times upload and/or download very tiny files to it. The program *only* runs via Task Scheduler, and should do so with *no* user interaction.

I have gone down the LiveSDK and OneDrive SDK routes with no joy, trying to get a simple example of fully logging on with Client ID & Secret, with no success.

At this point I am in need of knowing whether what I am trying to do is even *possible*. I have a similar, but more detailed, question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38229475/how-to-utilize-code-flow-for-onedrive-api) about OAuth2, which is concerned with the same use case.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes - after the initial authorization.**

If the first run of the application there is prompt for username/password and the consent flow validation with the `offline_access` scope then further authentication attempts will not require user interaction.

Comment: No expiration? No timeouts?

Comment: There is a limit on the stored refresh token of a year, which could  change, whereby you would need to interactively reauthenticate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It got far too difficult, so we just switched to GSuite, where everything just works. Well, except rsync'ing to it at speed... Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The primary way of accessing OneDrive as well as SharePoint online is through powershell. Create the process in powershell first. Then once it is working startup powershell from the C# service and use the calls done in the previous step.

- See [Using the Windows Live APIs from PowerShell](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/04/07/using-the-windows-live-apis-from-powershell/) to get started on the powershell commands to onedrive.
- See a C# example of executing powershell scripts- [Execute PowerShell Script from C# with Commandline Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527513/execute-powershell-script-from-c-sharp-with-commandline-arguments)

Comment: I may have done this wrong, but the new API required me to authenticate via a form. Have you tried this approach with the new API? You (?) put a **TON** of work into it, either way. I would love to see the example migrated for OneDrive!

Comment: @YumiKoizumi I have worked on SharePoint online where we authenticate all in powershell calls. I haven't tried an operation on OneDrive yet, but I believe the concept should be scriptable without popping up a authentication form.